# ASP.NET MVC Session with ID in custom header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

Is it possible in ASP.NET MVC (without writing toooo much code) to manually select what the current sessionId is? I don't mean like creating my own sessionId, but rather I want to store the sessionId in a custom header instead of in a cookie or the url. I don't mind if I need to read the header myself and do something like this in request_start:

```
Request.Session = new SessionState(Request.Headers["sessionId"]);
```

The main thing is that I don't want to store the session-state in a cookie (since cookies won't be enabled on the device that's supposed to talk to the mvc-application), and I don't want to have to parse the url on the client to then resend everything with the sessionId inserted into the url.

Also, if I can't do this with the native Session-object I don't really mind that either, I just need a fast and easy solution to having a token in a custom header rather than a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you mention not wanting to parse the url, but using the url with routing appear to be a simple and fast solution, add the parameter to your routes:

In your Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "SessionIdUrl",
  "{sessionId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Create a base controller and make the SessionId available to your controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  public string UrlSessionId { get; set; }

  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    object sessionId = "";
    if (filterContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("sessionId", out sessionId))
    {
      UrlSessionId = sessionId.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

On your controller inherits from this base controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
```

So your controller has access to base.UrlSessionId.

When the user signed in, start using the sessionId in your Url;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(User data)
{
  // authenticate
  return RedirectToAction("AfterSignedIn", new { sessionId = Session.SessionID, id = "my id" } );
}
```

On your views, create your link with the SessionId like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My link", "ActionWithUrlSession", "YourController", new { sessionId = Session.SessionID, id = "my id" }, null)
```

Here you go, you can actually use anything else than Session.SessionID, you might as well be better of with something identifying the current loged in user maybe.

Comment: How does that help with session-handling?